# Add a column with PHP and HTML (MYSQLI)

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to make a input type and if I fill in the text it must automatically go to my phpmyadmin. How can I add columns with php code?

### This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
include 'connectie.php';

?>

<html>
<head>
  <?php
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE 'prijzen' ADD 'test' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ";

  ?>

</head>


<body>


<h1>Voeg Hier uw Kolom naam</h1>

    <form method="post" action="">

      Career Name
      <input type="text" name="test" size="20">

     <input type="submit"
      name="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the query I had added IGNORE to the SQL statement:

```
$sql = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE 'prijzen' ADD 'test' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ";
mysqli_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE TRY THIS

```
<html>
<?php
    $con=new mysqli("localhost","","root","database123");
    if(isset($_REQUESET['sub']))
    {
        $fldname=$_REQUEST['fieldname'];
        $sqlalt="alter table `tablename` add `$fldname` varchar(100)";
        $con->query($sqlalt);
        echo "column add in tablename"."ok??";
    }
?>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fieldname">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="add field">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 

if (!$mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test date varchar(255) NOT NULL")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

This [link](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-use-mysqli_connect-in-php_336.html) will help you.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks man for your reply. But im getting a weird message on the top:Table creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''prijzen' ADD 'test' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1